# Dropping rows using multiple criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following data frame:

| EID | CLEAN_NAME | Start_Date | End_Date | Rank_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E000000 | DEF | 3/1/1973 | 2/28/1978 | 154 |
| E000001 | GHI | 6/1/1983 | 3/31/1988 | 1296 |
| E000001 | ABC | 1/1/2017 |  | 80292 |
| E000002 | JKL | 10/1/1980 | 8/31/1981 | 751.5 |
| E000003 | MNO | 5/1/1973 | 11/30/1977 | 157 |
| E000003 | ABC | 5/1/1977 | 11/30/1987 | 200 |
| E000003 | PQR | 5/1/1987 | 11/30/1997 | 300 |
| E000003 | ABC | 5/1/1997 |  | 1000 |

What I am trying to do here is I am trying to delete company ABC where rank is highest for ABC company in Rank_no column for each EID. If we find ABC record but it does not have highest rank for an EID it should not be deleted. Rest of the data should remain as it is. The expected output is as follows:

| EID | CLEAN_NAME | Start_Date | End_Date | Rank_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E000000 | DEF | 3/1/1973 | 2/28/1978 | 154 |
| E000001 | GHI | 6/1/1983 | 3/31/1988 | 1296 |
| E000002 | JKL | 10/1/1980 | 8/31/1981 | 751.5 |
| E000003 | MNO | 5/1/1973 | 11/30/1977 | 157 |
| E000003 | ABC | 5/1/1977 | 11/30/1987 | 200 |
| E000003 | PQR | 5/1/1987 | 11/30/1997 | 300 |

I tried to use the following code:

```
result_new = result.drop(result[(result['Rank_no'] == result.Rank_no.max()) & (result['CLEAN_NAME'] == 'ABC')].index)
```

But it's not working. Pretty sure I am giving the conditions incorrect but not sure what exactly I am missing or writing incorrectly. I have named my data frame as result.

Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks.!

Comment: do you get an error or does it simply not filter the dataframe?

Comment: @Sherif Eweis It was not filtering the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) to find the max index for each respective `EID` and `CLEAN_NAME` combo after filtering down to only the rows that have `ABC`.

```
df.drop(df.loc[df.CLEAN_NAME == "ABC"].groupby("EID").Rank_no.idxmax())

       EID CLEAN_NAME Start_Date    End_Date  Rank_no
0  E000000        DEF   3/1/1973   2/28/1978    154.0
1  E000001        GHI   6/1/1983   3/31/1988   1296.0
3  E000002        JKL  10/1/1980   8/31/1981    751.5
4  E000003        MNO   5/1/1973  11/30/1977    157.0
5  E000003        ABC   5/1/1977  11/30/1987    200.0
6  E000003        PQR   5/1/1987  11/30/1997    300.0
```

Comment: this worked as a perfect solution.! thanks upvoted it.!

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

datas = [
    ['E000000', 'DEF', '3/1/1973', '2/28/1978', 154],
    ['E000001', 'GHI', '6/1/1983', '3/31/1988', 1296],
    ['E000001', 'ABC', '1/1/2017', '', 80292],
    ['E000002', 'JKL', '10/1/1980', '8/31/1981', 751.5],
    ['E000003', 'MNO', '5/1/1973', '11/30/1977', 157],
    ['E000003', 'ABC', '5/1/1977', '11/30/1987', 200],
    ['E000003', 'PQR', '5/1/1987', '11/30/1997', 300],
    ['E000003', 'ABC', '5/1/1997', '', 1000],
]

result = pd.DataFrame(datas, columns=['EID', 'CLEAN_NAME', 'Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Rank_no'])

new_result = result.sort_values(by='Rank_no')  # sort by lowest Rank_no
new_result = new_result.drop_duplicates(subset=['CLEAN_NAME'], keep='first')  # drop duplicates keeping the first
new_result = new_result.sort_values(by='EID')  # sort by EID

print(new_result)
```

Output :

```
   EID CLEAN_NAME Start_Date    End_Date  Rank_no
0  E000000        DEF   3/1/1973   2/28/1978    154.0
1  E000001        GHI   6/1/1983   3/31/1988   1296.0
3  E000002        JKL  10/1/1980   8/31/1981    751.5
4  E000003        MNO   5/1/1973  11/30/1977    157.0
5  E000003        ABC   5/1/1977  11/30/1987    200.0
6  E000003        PQR   5/1/1987  11/30/1997    300.0
```